# How do I get a key given a value using Java APIs only?

Tags: java, treemap

So, what I have here is a Red Black Tree implementation of a Dictionary (aka Map). I am trying to find and return the corresponding key given a value using the getKey() method. I am trying to achieve this using only Java APIs. If you know more than one way to do it, please list a few. Also, if there is a problem with any of the my method definitions please inform me of the proper way to do it.

```
TreeMap<K,V> tree;

public RedBlackTree() {
    tree = new TreeMap<K,V>();
}

public boolean contains(K key) {
    return tree.containsKey(key);
}

public boolean add(K key, V value) {
    tree.put(key, value);
    return true;
}

public boolean delete(K key) {
    if(!contains(key))
        return false;
    tree.remove(key);
    return true;
}

public V getValue(K key) {
    V ret = tree.get(key);
    return ret;
}

public K getKey(V value) {
    //HOW DO I DO THIS?
}

public int size() {
    return tree.size();
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return false;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return tree.size() == 0;
}

public void clear() {
    tree.clear();
}

public Iterator<K> keys() {
    return tree.keySet().iterator();
}

public Iterator<V> values() {
    return tree.values().iterator();
}
```

}

Comment: Looks like your homework?

Comment: One possibility: iterates over `keys()`, `getValue()` for each one, compare to your `value` parameter and if equals you have the first matching key. (NB: there might be many keys with a `value`)

Comment: You will need to find a method that returns all the keys and values, then search through it looking for a value that matches.  (The `TreeMap` does not order things by value, so a brute force search will be necessary.)  Start by looking at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) for a method that returns the keys and values.

Comment: @JavaLava homework, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that there may be several keys for the same value:

```
    TreeMap<Object, Object> tree = new TreeMap();
    tree.put(1, 1);
    tree.put(2, 1);
```

this is how to get the keys for the specified value with  Java 8

```
    Object value = 1;
    Object[] keys = tree.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> value.equals(e.getValue()))
            .map(e -> e.getKey()).toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public K getKey(V value) {
       for (Map.Entry entry:tree.entrySet()){
           if (entry.getValue().equals(value))
               return (K) entry.getKey();
       }
       return null;        
}
```